# Make the sections of your flag history into links and notify users of declined flags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, declined-flags, flag-history

I have the following flag history statistics:

[image: Flag history]

I suggest making each of the entries into links so that the user can easily sort the flags shown. For example, if I wanted to know which of my moderator attention flags were declined, I just click on the respective link and only those entries will be displayed. As it is now, I would have to scroll through 212 flags to try to find the declined ones - something that many users will not do. Allowing users to quickly sort through their flags will give them a better picture of what they are doing wrong (and right) to prevent incorrectly flagging things in the future.

Also, it may not be a bad idea to notify the user whenever one of their flags was declined/disputed for the same reason. Many users won't check their flag history and won't notice when one of their flags was declined and may continue to incorrectly flag in the future.